# Find the length |PB|

Tags: geometry

Any tip, helpful advice would be appreciated!

Given A, B, P, O, where |AP|=|OP|=6, find |PB|?
[image: picture]

I have thought about this for a while, but I can not evaluate it unless I have more information!

P.S: Sorry for amateurish figure, made it really quick, but it is the general geometrical representation of the problem.

Comment: I think there is insufficient information.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve a set of equations:

$6+x = AB$

$\sqrt{6^2-(AB/2)^2} = OM$ where M is the midpoint (AB/2)

Then finally $\sqrt{6^2 - OM^2} = AM -AP$